# useEffect in a custom hook freezes my react-native app when the hook is used in more than one place

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have created a custom hook that fetches setting from an api that uses Async-Storage.

```
// Takes the key/name of the setting to retrieve
export const useSettings = (key) => {

  // stores the json string result in the setting variable
  const [setting, setSetting] = useState("");

  const deviceStorage = useContext(DeviceStorageContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    getValue()
     .then(value => setSetting(value));
  }, []);

  // gets value from my custom api that uses Async-Storage to handle r/w of the data.
  const getValue = async () => await deviceStorage.getValueStored(key);
  
  const setValue = async (value) => { 
      await deviceStorage.setValueStored(key, value);
      getValue().then(value => setSetting(value));
  };

  
  const removeValue = async () => { }

  return [setting, { setValue,removeValue }];
};
```

This works as expected in Main.jsx without any problem.

```
const Main = () => {
  const [units, operations] = useSettings('units');

  useEffect(() => {
    const initSettings = async () => {
      if (units) {
       console.log(units)
       return;
     }
      await operations.setValue({ pcs: 1, box: 20 });
    };
    initSettings();
  }, []);
```

However, when I even just call the useSetting hook in Form.jsx and visit the page, it freezes my entire app to just that page.

```
const FormView = ({ handleReset, handleSubmit }) => {
  const [setting,] = useSettings('units');
```

Removing the useState and useEffect fixes it and calling these methods directly works but I really don't want to call getValue() throughout my project and use async/await code to handle it.

Stuck on this for hours now. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome @foreign-native. Can you inspect your re-rendering? Is your custom hook or anything for that matter locking your app due to some re-rendering loop in useEffect?

Comment: @Chris Thank you. I have tried it. Everything seems to render the right amount of times without any issue except the useEffect in useSettings. I have tried putting a console.log to see how many times it gets called, but it doesn't print anything. I am assuming this is where it gets stuck in an infinite loop but I can't figure out why.

Comment: it actually sounds like if you cant see the console.log at all it isn't firing? If you saw the console.log a ton youd know it was in a loop lock. Also in your form code snippet, you prob just didnt copy but for clarity you did close FormView with } correct?

Comment: @Chris Yes. I did close FormView. It just renders a Form after this. I should clarify the getValue().then() inside my useEffect isn't printing anything. It prints when Main.jsx calls it but not when FormView calls it. I tried putting console.log inside getValue, it's then, and its catch. None of them print anything. Outside of that, useEffect itself prints fine even in FormView.

Comment: @Chris Nvm. It was a drop down library inside FormView that was messing it up. Removing that library fixed it. I still don't understand why. It wasn't using this hook in any way and only bothered when this hook was used. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Very interesting! Did you find it via try/catch? Great find foreign-native. Good luck with you project

Comment: @Chris Thank you. No, this dropdown component has been a huge pain throughout the project. It has been working fine for quite a while that's why I didn't think of it but when I noticed it, I removed it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a dropdown component library inside FormView that was messing it up. Removing that library fixed it.